# What is wrong? $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, radicals, epsilon-delta

$\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \sqrt{x}=1$

**My proof**:

We have that $0 < \lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta$ and $\rvert \sqrt{x}-1 \lvert \lt \epsilon$

$\lvert x \rvert -1\le\lvert x-1 \rvert \lt\delta$ which gives $\lvert x\rvert \lt \delta +1$

$\rvert\sqrt{x} \lvert -1 \le \rvert \sqrt{x}-1 \lvert \lt \epsilon$ Which gives $\rvert\sqrt{x} \lvert\lt \epsilon +1$ squaring and taking the absolute value gives us $ \rvert x \lvert \lt \lvert \epsilon^2 + 2\epsilon +1 \rvert$

Now simply let $\delta = \lvert \epsilon^2+2\epsilon +1\rvert-1$

There is something wrong in this proof,i suspect it's somewhere with me squaring the second inequality but i'm not sure.

**Second correct proof**:

We still have that $0 < \lvert x-1 \rvert < \delta$ and $\rvert \sqrt{x}-1 \lvert \lt \epsilon$

Also $$\lvert \sqrt{x}-1\rvert \lt \epsilon$$
$$\therefore -\epsilon \lt \sqrt{x}-1 \lt \epsilon$$
$$\therefore 1-2\epsilon +\epsilon^2 \lt x \lt 1+2\epsilon +\epsilon^2$$

Then

$$\rvert x-1 \lvert \lt \min(\lvert-2\epsilon +\epsilon^2\rvert, \lvert2\epsilon +\epsilon^2\rvert)$$

Now let $\delta = \min(\lvert-2\epsilon +\epsilon^2\rvert, \lvert2\epsilon +\epsilon^2\rvert)$

Which is correct. Given the similarity to the two solutions in the proofs there must be something small that's missing in the first proof, but I don't know what. Any help?

Comment: You should keep track of that the hypothesis is and what the conclusion is. Your first "proof" hardly makes sense.  $|x|<\delta $ should play no role at all.

Comment: By going $\sqrt{x} - 1\leq |\sqrt{x} - 1| < \varepsilon$ you lose the information that you're trying to bound from above the middle quantity and not just the left one. I think that's where the fault lies. (The middle quantity can be $1 - \sqrt{x}$ when $x \leq 1$.)

Comment: I think I get it. By finding a $\delta$ for which $\lvert \sqrt{x} \rvert-1 \lt \delta$ that doesn't imply that $\lvert \sqrt{x}-1\rvert \lt \delta$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sqrt x-1=\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x +1}$$Take absolute values and bound the denominator below by 1.

Comment: Ooooh! So we can just let $\delta =\epsilon$